# Error reading package lists

Tags: linux, terminal, apt-get, apt

I have been trying to get updates on my Quantal Desktop and `apt-get update` gives me the following:

```
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/sa.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_quantal_main_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I have tried deleting the file

```
sa.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_quantal_main_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS
```

and then apt-get update again and still get the same error. I have also tried visitng the actual directory through a browser (sa.archive.ubuntu.com/Ubuntu/quantal/main/i18n/Translation-en%5fUS) and that does not exist. What should I do now?

Comment: Please post the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and the result of `ls /etc/apt/sources.d`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I had was that my University was blocking the Ubuntu repos and mirrors. I tried opening up the file at:

> /var/lib/apt/lists/sa.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_quantal_main_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS

and it gives me the default page used by the IT department to block certain sites. My solution was to use VPN.